# dynamic button click android

Tags: android

I want to change the image of the button when clicked on particuar button and deselet all the other one please help.

This is my code

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Object tag = ((Button) view).getTag();

    System.out.println("value o ftagagdsgsdg:::" +tag.toString());
    String strtag = tag.toString();
    System.out.println("value of strtag:::" +strtag);

    enablebutton = Integer.valueOf(tag.toString());

    System.out.println("value of enable buttons variable::" +enablebutton);
    DeselectButtons();

    ((Button)view).setEnabled(true);
    for(int a = 0;a<adapt_obj.city_id_array.length;a++){
        System.out.println("ddsgdgsdg::"+adapt_obj.city_code_array[a]);
        System.out.println("value o ftagagdsgsdg:inside for loop::" +tag.toString());

        if(tag.toString() == adapt_obj.city_code_array[a]){
            ((Button)view).setFocusable(true);
            //clicked = false;

            // Calling process to fetch the data of city 
            selectedcityidclicked(tag.toString(), view);
            ((Button)view).setSelected(true);

            /*Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_btn_active_1);// active
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();
            // Scale it to 50 x 50
            // Set your new, scaled drawable "d"
            ((Button)view).setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 10, 10, true)));*/
           // ((Button)view).invalidate();
        }
        else if(tag.toString() != adapt_obj.city_code_array[a]){

            /*((Button)view).setFocusable(true);
            selectedcityidclicked(tag.toString(), view);
            Drawable dr2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_btn_active_1);// inactive
            Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) dr2).getBitmap();
            // Scale it to 50 x 50
            Drawable d2 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, 10, 10, true));
            // Set your new, scaled drawable "d"
            ((Button)view).setBackgroundDrawable(d2);
            ((Button)view).invalidate();
            clicked = false;*/
        }
    }

    /*else if(tag.toString() != adapt_obj.city_code_array[a]){
         ((Button)view).setFocusable(true);
        Drawable dr2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_btn_inactive_1);//instead of inactive
        Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) dr2).getBitmap();
        // Scale it to 50 x 50
        Drawable d2 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, 10, 10, true));
        // Set your new, scaled drawable "d"
        ((Button)view).setBackgroundDrawable(d2);
        ((Button)view).invalidate();
    }
    else {
        Drawable dr2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_btn_active_1);//white
        Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) dr2).getBitmap();
        // Scale it to 50 x 50
        Drawable d2 = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, 10, 10, true));
        // Set your new, scaled drawable "d"
        ((Button)view).setBackgroundDrawable(d2);
        ((Button)view).invalidate();
    }*/

    /*((Button) view).setText("*");
    //selectedcityidclicked(tag.toString());
    ((Button) view).setEnabled(false);*/
}
private void DeselectButtons() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int x=0; x<adapt_obj.city_code_array.length;x++){ 
        System.out.println("value of enable tag::" +enablebutton);
        System.out.println("valuie dofdsf xxx:::" +x);
        if (enablebutton!= x)
            //What should i do here as i had to take the un clicked button as set selected as false //
            // ((Button)view).setSelected(false);
            //this.findViewById(i).setSelected(false);
            //this.findViewById(i).setSelected(false);
    }
}
private void selectedcityidclicked(String cityval, View view) {
     cityidvalue = "&city_code="+cityval;
     System.out.println("value of cityidvalue::" +cityidvalue);

     new MyAsyncTask(view).execute();
}
```

Comment: you need to create an selector xml for your buttons

Comment: its a dynamic button whose number of values comes from the api and i am displaying it in the screen it works all fine just the problem is of changing image runtime

Comment: yes thats why i am saying use selector xml just create it and then use as button background

Comment: can u please help me by showing in my code please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059454/creating-buttons-dynamically-could-i-select-one-and-deselect-the-other-buttons please see this link its just exactly same but in deselectbuttons method after              if (enablebutton!= x) what should i do ?

Comment: so your problem is how to create dynamic buttons ??

Comment: no i created the dynamic button and displayed all the things are working fine the problem is: There are  two buttons displayed dynamically on the screen now when i click my first button then its image should be active and the other button should be inactive, similarly the same for the second one please help i m struggling since last two days please help

Comment: ok got you then you have to write down a logic as on click change the image of both button check my edited answer

Comment: i cant see ur edited answer where is it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this selector as drawable  of your button that will change its drawable when you click it or make it selected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/home_hover"></item>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/home_selected"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home"></item>
</selector>
```

For making other buttons unselected you need to loop them for e.g. put all your buttons in Linear or Relative layout than after fetching reference of that relative layout loop through its children and see for their tags. If they equal tag of buttons you wanna unselect than call setSelected(false) to that button.

```
private void DeselectButtons() {
    LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.parent_ofbuttons);
    for(int i=0; i<layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
         Button btn = (Button)layout.getChildAt(i);  
         if(btn.getTag().toString().equals("100")) {
              btn.setSelected(false);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059454/creating-buttons-dynamically-could-i-select-one-and-deselect-the-other-buttons please see this link its just exactly same but in deselectbuttons method after              if (enablebutton!= x) what should i do ?

Comment: just set tags of all of your buttons to 100 by setTag method of button

Comment: yes that's true but see my code i dont want to again make the linearlayout and deselect the button but just deselect that button which is not select from number of buttons please help i m struggling since last 2 days

Comment: These buttons must be added inside some parent layout. Just loop through that parent layout and see for tag of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

create an selector xml which is normally an xml

there in items set your images for android:state_pressedpressed="true" and android:state_pressed="false"

my_button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_image"></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_image"></item>
</selector>
```

then save this file in your drawable then set your button background to this file

as `myButton.setBackgroundResourceId(R.drawable.my_button_background);`

### -----------------------------

edited

```
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

now in your override onCLick

```
@Override
OnClick(View v)
{
   if(v.getId() == R.id.button1_id)
   {
      button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anyImage1);
      button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anyImage2);
   }
   else
   {
 if(v.getId() == R.id.button1_id)
   {
      button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anyImage2);
      button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anyImage1);
   }
   }
}
```

dont forget to declare button1 and button2 member variables